# Optimization of multi-band raster clip by polygon

Tags: postgis, raster, clip, optimization, postgis-raster

I have tiled (50x50), 365 band, rasters in my postgis database. Each band represents a day in a year.

I want to return the raster pixels which intersect with an input geometry, including all bands. I'd like to figure out the *most optimized* way of doing this.

Current Approach:

1. filter the raster table with ST_Intersects(rast,geom)
2. Clip raster to geom with ST_Clip(rast,geom)
3. St_Dumpvalues(clip) the result of clip to examine the band-pixel values of the clip

Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_time_series (start_year INT, end_year INT, geom geometry)
RETURNS TABLE (
    year INT,
    day_of_year INT,
    result float8[]
)
AS $$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY
 with myresult as(
        with myclip as (
            SELECT rast_table.rid,st_clip(rast_table.rast, geom) as clip,rast_table.year
                FROM rast_table_50x50 rast_table
            WHERE ST_Intersects(rast_table.rast, geom)
                AND rast_table.year BETWEEN start_year AND end_year
        )
        SELECT (st_dumpvalues(clip)).*,myclip.year from myclip
    )
    SELECT myresult.year,myresult.nband as day_of_year,valarray as result FROM myresult;

END; $$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Is there another approach which might yield better peformance?

Would a plpython function be of any use for optimizing the clip/mask operation?

Should I be clipping at all?

Comment: two suggestions 1. you might want to wrap st_union around the st_clip function 2. https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Intersection.html this is a raster/geom intersection function. it may or maybe not be faster worth checking it out though